# Why are all my fields updated when I change one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use the JQuery [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), and the problem is that I generate the HTML, so I don't know in advance the ID's of the fields.

My code can be tried at http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/KrEqk/

The forms below are generated, where the ID's just get prefixed with a random number to make them different.

What I did to get datepicker in those fields was to add `class="datepick"` to those fields like so

```
<input name="from" id="114_begin_date" value="16/05-2011" type="text" class="datepick" />
<input name="to"   id="114_end_date"   value="16/05-2011" type="text" class="datepick" />
```

and add `.datepick` to the inline datepicker JavaScript, like so

```
var dates = $("#from, #to, .datepick").datepicker({
```

If you try to change the dates several times you will notice, that all fields are updated =(

How do I prevent that from happening, so just the field that I click on is changed?

Comment: if you take the onSelect function out, it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `onSelect` handler

You are running

```
dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
```

this changes all the other datepickers to a single value (*the one of the current datepicker*)..

---

**Update** *for comment*

change your `onSelect` method to

```
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                  var self = this;
                  var option = this.name == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                  instance   = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                  date       = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                                  instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                  dates.filter(function(){return this.form === self.form;}).not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
               }
```

changes made

1. added the `var self = this;` for later use
2. use the `name` attribute instead of the `id` to decide which limit to use
3. instead of applying the new date limit to all other datepickers (*i assume you took that part from somewhere where only two datepickers existed*), we filter them down to the ones that are in the same form as the one we changed. (*in effect the other one, in the same line. Keep in mind that this works only for two datepickers per form named `from` and `to`*)

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Wy6qT/

Comment: How would the script look, so this doesn't happen?

Comment: The reason that line is there is to prevent the "end date" to be before the "begin date". But you are right, if I remove it, it works, but I loose some functionality.

Comment: That is incredible cool that you could change ID to Name! Thank you so much! And yes, I copied the datepicker authors example =) Thanks again =)

Answer (score 2):

Hm, i'm not familiar with datepicker, but you could try:

```
$("#from, #to, .datepick").each(
    $(this).datepicker({/*... some settings? */});
}
```